# nginx SSL and hsts questions

Tags: ssl, hsts

I have an Nginx with SSL already without HSTS.
But in the backend, few services are not https.
Is there any potential risk for the enable the HSTS?
I am worried about the HSTS header will break the internal route when the HSTS header exists, force redirect to HTTPS

For example

current:

public user -> https://www.123.com --- internal service ---> Http://internalA.123.com -> Http://internalA.123.com

Will it become below?

public user -> "https://www.123.com" --- internal service ---> Https://internalA.123.com -> Https://internalA.123.com

If yes, then The service will definitely break with HSTS

Answer (score 0):

HSTS is solely about the connection between client (browser) and web server (nginx). It does not matter what the server then does with the received data, i.e. if the data are processed locally or if the server is just a reverse proxy to some other server. Similar HTTPS between client and server does only protect the communication between these two and does neither protect any further connections from the reverse proxy nor does it secure local processing of data at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

HSTS is an instruction from the server (nginx) to client (browser) to say "hey next time just assume I'm on HTTPS." So in above scenario it will not be used for the back end connection as Steffen says.

However there are definitely a few dangers to be aware of:

First of all if you set this at the top level domain (e.g. 123.com) and use the `includeSubDomains` then every domain on 123.com is suddenly potentially given HSTS protection. This will likely still not affect your backend connections however if you happen to visit https://123.com in your browser (maybe you just typed that in the URL bar) and pick up that header and then try to visit http://intranet.123.com or http://dev.123.com or even http://dev.123.com:8080 then all of them will redirect to HTTPS and if they are not available over HTTPS then they will fail and you just can't visit those sites anymore. This can be difficult to track down as perhaps not many visit the bare domain so it "works fine for me".

Of course if you're only using HTTPS on all your sites on that domain (including all your internal sites) then this is not an issue but if not...

As an extra protection you can also submit your site to a preload list which will then be hardcoded into browsers in their next release, and some other client also use this hardcoded list. This is an extra protection though brings with it extra risks as one of the requirements for it is that the top level domain is included with `includeSubDomains`. I realise you haven't asked about this, but since you're asking about the risk of this I think it's well worth mentioning here. So, with preloading HSTS, it suddenly brings all above risks into play even **without** visiting https://123.com to pick up the header. And, as it's months (or even years) between browser releases this is basically irreversible. You could quite happily be running HSTS on your www domain, think it's all working fine and decide to upgrade to the preload list as well cause you've not seen any issues and suddenly with the next browser release all your HTTP-only internal sites stop working and you need to upgrade them all HTTPS immediately or they can't be accessed.

In summary take care with HSTS if still have some sites on HTTP-only at present. Consider only returning it on sites that need it (e.g. https://123.com **without** `includeSubdomains` and https://www.123.com **with** `includeSubdomains`) and be extra careful with preloading it. Personally I think preload is overkill for most sites but if you really want to do it, then best practice is to first load a resource from https://123.com on your home page with a small expiry and increase it slowly. That way everyone picks this up before submitting it to preload list and there are no surprises.

But HSTS is good, should be used on all public facing websites IMHO and I don't want this answer putting you off - just understand how it works and so the risks with it.

Comment: Thank you for all the details. This is really awesome answer.

Comment: Np. FYI I wrote about this a number of years back: https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/dangerous-web-security-features/